# Как работать с символами в const char*

Tags: c++

Есть переменная которая объявлена как `const char* str_value`. Нужно получить самое короткое слово в ней. Например, при выводе в цикле `printf("%s = ", str_value[i]);` программа завершается, а при сравнении с `" "` ругается на `char*`. Как это нужно исправить? Завершение даже при `printf("%s = ", str_value[1]);`

При выводе `printf("%d = ", str_value[1])`; выходит число. Это код символа? Почему?

Comment: А вы не сравнивайте символ со строкой. Сравнивайте с символом.

Comment: сравните его с ' '

Comment: @VladD Я пробовал, выкидывает из программы

Comment: @aaa: Ну так это уже другая ошибка. Без этого просто не компилируется, это в принципе неправильно, всё равно что складывать медведя и тригонометрию.

Comment: @Vlad компиляция проходит успешно. только предупреждение: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]

Comment: Потому что `str_value[i]` возвращает `char`.

Comment: попробуй `printf("%c = ", str_value[1]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно [так](https://ideone.com/OkYTar) должна выглядеть ваша функция:

```
void findShortestWord(const char* in, char* out)
{
    int len = strlen(in);

    int beginWord = 0;
    int lengthWord = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        while ( (in[i] == ' ') && ( in[i] != '\0')  ) i++;
        int begin = i;
        while ( (in[i] != ' ') && (in[i] != '\0') ) i++;
        int end = i;
        char tmp[256];
        for(int j = begin, k=0; j < end; j++, k++)
            tmp[k] = in[j];
        tmp[end - begin] = '\0';

        int currentLen = end - begin;
        if (currentLen > lengthWord)
        {
            lengthWord = currentLen;
            beginWord = begin;
        }
    }

    for (int i = beginWord, k = 0; i < beginWord + lengthWord; i++, k++)
        out[k] = in[i];

    out[lengthWord] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: _`(in[i] == ' ') && ( in[i] != '\0')`_ - бррррррр

Comment: а что здесь не так?

Comment: А пробел нулю равен? Вторая проверка бесполезна. Ну и паскалескобки, которые тут не нужны, т. к. приоритеты нормальные.

Comment: Здравствуйте, можете привести пример вызову функции? я до сих пор мучаюсь. хочу передать в in S_object.get() а в out переменную char*. Получаю ошибку при выполнении. Как мне её вызвать?

Comment: Я не знаю что такое `S_object.get()` и как вы пытаетесь передать параметры поэтому ничего не могу сказать, лучше создаете отдельный вопрос